# Draw rectangles in a circular pattern in turtle graphics

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

To make use of the turtle methods and functionalities, we need to import turtle. “turtle”
comes packed with the standard Python package and need not be installed externally.
The roadmap for executing a turtle program follows 3 steps:
a- Import the turtle module.
b- Create a turtle to control.
c- Draw around using the turtle methods.

[i need to make this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETe3X.png)

Instructions:

- You should use the shown colors for the rectangles.
- You can choose the side’s length/ width for the rectangle, keeping the general view
  of the output like the given diagram.
- Make sure to properly set the starting position (x & y) of your drawing, to maintain
  the above diagram (at the center).

[NOTE!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJdIY.png)

here is my code:

```
from turtle import *

# Set up the screen and turtle
screen = Screen()
t = Turtle()
t.speed(1)  # You can adjust the speed as needed

# Define colors
color_fill = "yellow"
color_border = "blue"
border_size = 5
gap_size = 10
rectangle_width = 50  # Adjust the width as needed
rectangle_height = 100  # Adjust the height as needed
circle_radius = 50  # Adjust the radius for the circular space

# Function to draw a colored rectangle with a border
def draw_rectangle_with_border(fill_color, border_color, border_size, width, height):
    # Draw the border
    t.pencolor(border_color)
    t.pensize(border_size)
    t.penup()
    t.goto(-width / 2, -height / 2)
    t.pendown()
    for _ in range(2):
        t.forward(width)
        t.left(90)
        t.forward(height)
        t.left(90)

    # Draw the fill
    t.fillcolor(fill_color)
    t.begin_fill()
    for _ in range(2):
        t.forward(width)
        t.left(90)
        t.forward(height)
        t.left(90)
    t.end_fill()

# Set the starting position
t.penup()
t.goto(0, -rectangle_height / 2)

# Draw the central circular space
t.pencolor("white")  # Set the color to match the background
t.fillcolor("white")
t.penup()
t.goto(0, -circle_radius)
t.pendown()
t.begin_fill()
t.circle(circle_radius)
t.end_fill()

# Calculate the total number of rectangles to form a complete circle
num_rectangles = 8
angle = 360 / num_rectangles

# Draw the circular pattern of rectangles around the central circular space
for _ in range(num_rectangles):
    draw_rectangle_with_border(color_fill, color_border, border_size, rectangle_width, rectangle_height)
    t.penup()
    t.goto(0, -rectangle_height / 2)
    t.left(angle)
    t.forward(gap_size)

# Close the window on click
screen.exitonclick()
```

and here is the output:

[the output i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYk4J.png)

and i am want to have this output :

[the wanted output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I753y.png)

Comment: The "NOTE!!" suggests using `from turtle import *` is poor advice. Sure, it saves a couple keystrokes, but it also leads to tons of potential bugs by dumping 100+ functions in the global namespace, where they can easily be overwritten by your local variables and create confusion between functional and instance modes. Also, don't forget to ask a specific question about your attempt. Your output seems like it just needs a pen up/move forward/pen down/draw box/pen up/move back sequence, more or less.

Comment: @ggorlen turtle is used to teach programming, not be used to engineer huge long-lasting applications, and different principles apply. "Typing less" is important for beginners, namespace pollution is not.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @julaine It's not a matter of engineering, it's a matter of bug avoidance. When a library intended for beginners has as many footguns as Py turtle does, it's extremely frustrating for beginners. Using a namespace helps avoid hours of wasted effort. Two characters more of typing per line, plus a one-time initializer invocation seems worth the tradeoff for 99% of students, in my view. At least if a teacher does opt for the wildcard import, they should communicate the risks of it so the student can watch out for typical aliasing bugs and instance mode/functional interface confusion.

Comment: @julaine Here's another possible compromise: don't use the wildcard import, but import each necessary function explicitly. Still more typing, but realistically, they'll probably only need a half-dozen functions, and make sure `Turtle` isn't one of the imports to "disable" the instance mode. This could be provided to the student as a starter file with the necessary functions pre-imported. Something like `from turtle import forward, left, right, penup, pendown, exitonclick, goto, setheading`. All commands are now obvious and collisions less likely. Abbreviated commands can be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rectangles look pretty good, although you don't need to draw the fill and outline separately. All that's missing is moving forward and backward from the start point to the corner of each square:

```py
from turtle import Screen, Turtle


def draw_rectangle_with_border(t, width, height):
    t.pendown()
    t.begin_fill()

    for _ in range(2):
        t.forward(height)
        t.left(90)
        t.forward(width)
        t.left(90)

    t.end_fill()
    t.penup()


def draw_rectangles_in_circle(t):
    color_fill = "yellow"
    color_border = "blue"
    border_size = 9
    rectangle_width = 60
    rectangle_height = 90
    circle_radius = 110
    num_rectangles = 8
    angle = 360 / num_rectangles
    t.pencolor(color_border)
    t.pensize(border_size)
    t.fillcolor(color_fill)
    t.penup()
    
    for _ in range(num_rectangles):
        t.forward(circle_radius)
        draw_rectangle_with_border(t, rectangle_width, rectangle_height)
        t.backward(circle_radius)
        t.left(angle)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    turtle = Turtle()
    draw_rectangles_in_circle(turtle)
    Screen().exitonclick()
```

Now, the actual image has a little bit of overlap from square to square, so you could do a mini-turn to make that happen and adjust to taste:

```py
# ...
    t.penup()
    t.right(5)
    
    for _ in range(num_rectangles):
        t.forward(circle_radius)
        t.left(5)
        draw_rectangle_with_border(t, rectangle_width, rectangle_height)
        t.right(5)
        t.backward(circle_radius)
        t.left(angle)
# ...
```

Note that the `from turtle import *` advice is questionable. This adds over 100 methods into the global namespace, making it easy to encounter aliasing bugs and confusion between instance and functional interfaces. You're only using `Screen` and `Turtle` from turtle, so it's easy to import what you need explicitly, as shown above.

Comment: Thank you so much for your invaluable help!  Your code provided the perfect solution to my challenge, and I really appreciate the effort you put into explaining and optimizing it. The adjustments you made not only resolved my issue but also enhanced the visual appeal of my project. Your expertise has made a significant impact, and I'm grateful for your generosity in sharing your knowledge. Thanks again! 

Answer (score 2):

As always, @ggorlen's answer is excellent (+1), particularly the advice on how to import turtle.  With `from turtle import *` we see issues where programmers don't understand which are *turtle instance* methods and which are *screen instance* methods.  The explicit import reduces this problem.

Of course, in the interest of "better living through stamping", I've an alternate solution:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

COLOR_FILL = 'yellow'
COLOR_BORDER = 'blue'
BORDER_SIZE = 4

NUMBER_RECTANGLES = 8
RECTANGLE_WIDTH = 30
RECTANGLE_HEIGHT = 50
CIRCLE_RADIUS = 30

OFFSET_FROM_PERFECT = 15  # in degrees (0 = perfect)
CURSOR_SIZE = 20

screen = Screen()
turtle = Turtle()
turtle.speed('fastest')
turtle.shape('square')
turtle.penup()

turtle.color(COLOR_BORDER, COLOR_FILL)
turtle.shapesize(RECTANGLE_WIDTH / CURSOR_SIZE, RECTANGLE_HEIGHT / CURSOR_SIZE, BORDER_SIZE)

turtle.sety(-CIRCLE_RADIUS)  # center image on current x, y
turtle.circle(CIRCLE_RADIUS, extent=OFFSET_FROM_PERFECT)

for _ in range(NUMBER_RECTANGLES):
    turtle.right(90 + OFFSET_FROM_PERFECT)
    turtle.forward(RECTANGLE_HEIGHT)
    turtle.stamp()
    turtle.backward(RECTANGLE_HEIGHT)
    turtle.left(90 + OFFSET_FROM_PERFECT)

    turtle.circle(CIRCLE_RADIUS, extent=360/NUMBER_RECTANGLES)

turtle.hideturtle()
screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]